# Return an average from an array of hash

Tags: javascript, arrays, hashmap, hashtable, average

I am new to working with hashes in javascript and would like to write a function that takes an array of hash and returns the average "grade" for a class.

Here is an example:

Input:

```
    {"string": "John", "integer": 7},
    {"string": "Margot", "integer": 8},
    {"string": "Jules", "integer": 4},
    {"string": "Marco", "integer": 19}
```

Output: 9.5

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @JaromandaX: I'm sure he would. That's not a question.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```js
let items = [
    {"string": "John", "integer": 7},
    {"string": "Margot", "integer": 8},
    {"string": "Jules", "integer": 4},
    {"string": "Marco", "integer": 19}
]

let avg = items.reduce((a, b) => a + b.integer, 0) / items.length

console.log(avg)
```

Comment: Don't know why your original answer was getting downvoted. Aside from not handling zero-length arrays, it seemed correct to me.

Comment: @slappy I think it copped some downvotes when it was producing `[object Object]8419`

Comment: @Phil: I must've missed that version.

Answer (score 3):

Operations like *average* and *sum* are best done using an [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) operation.

You can use `reduce` to produce a sum, then divide that result by the array length

```js
const arr = [
  {"string": "John", "integer": 7},
  {"string": "Margot", "integer": 8},
  {"string": "Jules", "integer": 4},
  {"string": "Marco", "integer": 19}
]

const avg = arr.reduce((sum, hash) => sum + hash.integer, 0) / arr.length

console.info(avg)
```